# Dependency Injection of functions with Factories (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-factory

I have a few functions that are used in different controllers, and rather than copy and paste it multiple times into the controllers, I want to pull it out and place it in a factory.

However, when I try to call the function in the HTML via Angular `{{expressions}}` it doesn't work.

Instead, I've made functions inside each of the controllers' $scopes that call the factory's functions so the DOM can read the expressions--but that seems redundant. Is there a way to fix this so I can simply call functions from the factory?

Here was what I originally had tried:

**index.html**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    The rating of this item is: {{MakeGraph.getRating(whichItem)}}<br />
    The votes of this item is: {{MakeGraph.getVotes(whichItem)}}
</div>
```

**MyController.js**:

```
controllers.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MakeGraph', '$routeParams', function($scope, MakeGraph, $routeParams){
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    //no other reference to MakeGraph here
}])
```

**factory.js**:

```
app.factory('MakeGraph', function(){
    var service = {};

    service.getRating = function(itemNo){
        ...
        return ...;
    };

    service.getVotes = function(itemNo){
        ...
        return ...;
    };

    return service;

});
```

Instead, I can only get it to work when I change MyController to have something like this:

```
$scope.getRating = function(){
    return MakeGraph.getRating(itemNo);
};
```

Can I fix this so I don't have to call the function inside the $scope? Thanks.

Comment: a quick way is angular.extend($scope,MyService)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `$scope.MakeGraph = MakeGraph` to your controller

```
controllers.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MakeGraph', '$routeParams', function($scope, MakeGraph, $routeParams){
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.MakeGraph = MakeGraph
}])
```

then you could access `MakeGraph` from your view

example:

```
<a ng-click="MakeGraph.getVotes(12)"> Click me </a>
```

note that if you return promises in your service, you will probably still need to wrap then in your controller in order to properly handle the `.success / .then / .error ...` events

Comment: So then the DOM **only** has access to $scope variables within a controller, even if something is passed into the controller (but not specifically labelled on the $scope)?

Thanks!